# Giving node command line params via package.json

Tags: node.js, jestjs

The following quote comes from the [Jest documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-webpack.html):

> Notice that Proxy is enabled in Node.js v6.* by default; if you are
>   not on Node v6.* yet, make sure you invoke Jest using node
>   --harmony_proxies node_modules/.bin/jest.

I'm running my tests with `npm test`.  Is there any way to configure package.json (or something else) so that the --harmony_proxies is passed to node when I do `npm test`

I'm hoping there is some package.json foo I could use for this.  I'd like to take advantage of the npm scripts that are in package.json rather than have to create a bunch of individual script files that do this kind of thing.

Comment: What is `scripts.test` set to in your package.json?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to override the test script with:

```
{
  // ...
  "scripts": {
    "test: "node --harmony_proxies server.js node_modules/.bin/jest",
  }
}
```